# Scikit-learn GridSearchCV - Why am I receiving a data type error when I execute grid.fit()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I have been working on a Machine Learning project in python. After getting a basic neural net running well, I am trying to set up a grid search to optimize the parameters using the `GridSearchCV` function from `sklearn`. The `grid.fit(X,Y)` function is throwing this error: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. My interpretation is that the fit function doesn't like the format of the `X` and `Y` I gave it. This is confusing to me because the net was running fine without the grid search and I didn't mess with the network or the data at all. Can anybody explain what is happening here and how I could fix it?

This code creates the network and the grid search:

```
#Creating the neural network
def create_model():
  model=Sequential()

  model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu',input_shape=(2606,)))
  model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

  opt=optimizers.Adam(lr=learn_rate)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

  #I commented this out because I believe it is delegated to the grid.fit() fn later on.
  #model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=30, epochs=6000, verbose=1)

  return model

#Now setting up the grid search
model=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model())

learn_rate=np.arange(.00001,.001,.00002).tolist()
batch_size=np.arange(10,2606,2).tolist()
epochs=np.arange(1000,10000,100).tolist()

param_grid=dict(learn_rate=learn_rate, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)

grid_results=grid.fit(X_train,Y_train) #This is the line referenced in the error message.

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
The `X_train` data has shape `(167,2606)`. Each of the 167 elements are an array of length 2606. This is why the `input_shape` for the network is `(2606,)`. The `Y_train` has shape `(167,)`.

Comment: What is the shape of your `X_train` and `Y_train` inputs? The error you are receiving is because under the hood of `fit()`, at some point, it is expecting a single scalar value and instead receiving an array.

Comment: I added the shapes as an edit to the question. I wonder where its expecting but not receiving a scalar. I assumed the issue was in ```fit()``` simply receiving the data. I didn't think about somewhere further along in the execution, as you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that `GridSearchCV` creates a new model with the new parameters for every combination thereof. You are passing an already created model, and a list of parameters. I believe that is the source of the array vs scalar error. Below, I've altered your code (with some garbage sample data) that will run.

The primary changes to take note of are that I altered the signature of your `create_model` to accept the parameters values you pass into the GridSearch. I also removed your assignment of the `KerasClassifier` instance to the variable `model` and instead put that call as the estimator in `GridSearchCV`.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


#Creating the neural network
def create_model(learn_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    model=Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu',input_shape=(2606,)))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

    opt=optimizers.Adam(lr=learn_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

    #I commented this out because I believe it is delegated to the grid.fit() fn later on.
    #model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=30, epochs=6000, verbose=1)

    return model

#Now setting up the grid search
X_train = np.empty((167,2606), dtype=float, order='C')
Y_train = np.empty((167,), dtype=float, order='C')

learn_rate=np.arange(.00001,.001,.00002).tolist()
batch_size=np.arange(10,2606,2).tolist()
epochs=np.arange(1000,10000,100).tolist()

param_grid=dict(learn_rate=learn_rate, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model), 
param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)

grid_results=grid.fit(X_train,Y_train) #This is the line referenced in the error message.

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I definitely missed the fact that I forgot to give parameters for ```create_model()``` to accept. It does seem to be up and running now. I'm expecting it to take a good long while so I'll try to give an update whenever it finishes, too. Thanks again!

Comment: A couple weeks later, I have been able to get the GridSearch to run completely. Biggest lesson learned is that it can take a very, very long time if you're too ambitious with the parameter grid. I was using the Google Colab GPU and still, the first 10 or so attempts were too ambitious to be able to execute in a reasonable time.

Comment: That is certainly a valuable lesson to learn! Thank you for the update. I'm glad you were able to get it running. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted for future users to know it's solid.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do that earlier (noob, can ya tell?) I just found the button though! Thanks!